# How to migrate "dirty" SVN working copy to clean SVN+GIT environment?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, sourceforge

I have a working copy of a project on sourceforge which has many small modifications from the trunk. I submit some of these as patches. Some will be accepted, I assume; some won't. In the meantime, every time I do an update, chaos ensues because some of the modifications are major rewrites of certain files.

So I think what I want to do is have a local git repository that I work in, and periodically do stash, ,stash-apply.

My question is: how do I get started? Do I simply use git-svn to checkout from the svn repository, then copy over my old local working copy (minus .svn dirs)?

Am I even going about this right?

Two factors that should make life simpler are that 1) I'm not very fussed about local history, and 2) I only have read access to the SVN repository.

Comment: Actually I realise that I can't simply copy my local files over, as there are unmerged changes in the repository that would be lost. Ack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things correctly. Use git-svn to keep branches of svn up to date. Merge any new changes from them to any branches that you have locally in git. Since it's read only, you don't have to worry about committing to svn which should save you some headaches.

Hope this helps